# Estimation of the probability distribution of process capabilities in SPC

Tags: probability, statistics

To better explain the point, let me report some preliminary details.
In SPC (statistical process control, a branch of process control devoted to quality that aims at ensuring data compliance with some requirements by using statistics and data analysis), I may deal with data having multifarious probability distributions; in a more general way, we could state that if $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an $n$-dimensional vector consisting of measured values (for example, produced by a manufacturing process, where the need of collecting data to ensure good performance is crucial), then $\mathbf{x}$ follows a probability distribution $\mathcal{X}$ whose characteristics are not known in advance: it could be a normal distribution, a Weibull distribution, or whatever you like the most.

Starting from $\mathbf{x}$, SPC relies on some performance indicators, such as process capability indices: these tell how good data "fit" within a given specification range, usually consisting of both an upper and a lower bound; we call these bounds USL (Upper Specification Limit) and LSL (Lower Specification Limit), respectively. Sometimes, a target value might be provided as well, but let us not consider it here. A very popular process capability index is called Ppk and is being defined as follows: Ppk = $\min$(PpL, PpU), where PpL$=\frac{USL-\mu}{3\sigma}$ and PpU=$\frac{\mu-LSL}{3\sigma}$ **iff** $\mathcal{X}$~$\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$; however, $\mathcal{X}$ is not always a normal distribution and therefore the previous equations might not be valid. Now, suppose I collect $m$ $n$-dimensional samples and for each sample a process capability index is calculated; in the previous example, I have just used Ppk as main indicator and therefore I call PpK$_i$ the PpK of the $i$-th $n$-dimensional sample; in the end, I end up having an $m$-dimensional vector **Ppk** that follows another probability distribution, let me call it $\mathcal{P}$.

My question therefore is the following: is there any theoretical result that can relate the unknown $\mathcal{X}$ distribution to $\mathcal{P}$?